# marking answers as favorite

Tags: support, bookmarks

Instead of marking Questions as favorite, can I mark specific answers as favorite?

This would help me to keep all my favorite tweaks/tricks/solutions at one place (favorite tab)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it is not possible to favorite an answer in SE. You can only favorite a question.
Maybe you can change this to a feature request, though I doubt it'll be accepted or implemented in the near future.

Meanwhile however, you can bookmark or save a link to the answer you wish to favorite in your own browser.